Getting/Setting properties for existing artifact 'Folder' in Artifactory using CLI or REST api
I'm looking for CLI or Rest API(Prefered) command which allows to SET/GET/UPDATE properties to artifact folder with specified repository name.
Is it possible? How to do it?
The folder need not be uploaded, it's already there.
THe documentation here says we can place properties on both artifacts and folders - https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/working-with-jfrog-properties
I tried following this - https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/get-item-properties Doesnt work for folder only works for artifact file.
same for setting a property.
